# Converting date format 01-01-1990 to 01-jan-1990

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help me to convert date format of my query.

My query

```
select pr.[Date], p.[Product]  
from tbl_ProTest p   
inner join tbl_Prod2 pr on P.[PID] = pr.[PID]
```

In my output I am getting date as `1990-01-01` but my expected output is `01-Jan-1990`.

Comment: And what **datatype** is your column `[Date]` in the `tbl_Prod2` table?

Comment: [Date] col is in tbl_Prod2 and it is of Date datatype

Comment: FYI Data formatting should really be done in your application, not in the database

Comment: Yes @cjk Data formatting should be done in application.Here according to my situation I have to do it in sql.Anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), pr.[Date], 106), ' ', '-')
```

This way date is cast to `VARCHAR` and you get it displayed in the required format. More about `CONVERT` and supported formats can be found **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)**

Comment: Hi, As iam new to sql I don't know about this 106..is it sql inbuilt format?.

Comment: 106 is a value for the 'style' parameter of the `CONVERT` function. It determines how the output will be formatted, it outputs following format `dd mon yy`. I further replaced blank spaces with `-` to get the required format. Please be aware that 106 format is classified as non-deterministic format, i.e. it's output can vary depending on the language settings. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
select DATE_FORMAT(pr.[Date],'%d %b %y'),p.[Product] from tbl_ProTest p  
inner join tbl_Prod2  pr on P.[PID] = pr.[PID]
```

Comment: Yes sql does not have DATE_FORMAT function

Answer (score -1):

you may use this

```
            mysql_select_db("datetime", $con);
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM datetime_test");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     foreach( $row as $lists){

       echo "".date('M d Y',strtotime($lists['date']));

     }

     }
```

Comment: What if he isn't using PHP?  And we know he isn't using MySql.

Comment: i am not sure but it help u                                                    SELECT GETDATE()
GO
-- SQL Server 2000/2005
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly;
GO
-- SQL Server 2008 Onwards
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS HourMinuteSeconds;
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) AS DateOnly;
GO

Comment: Thank You @ShivendraSuman I am using sql-server 2008 and your information in comment  is helpful